# replace/set tomcat welcome page with root root page

Tags: java, tomcat

I removed all default webapps including manager from the tomcat, and I deployed my app as extracted war file into `CATALINA/webapps/ROOT` folder, and everything perfect if I request my site with its name `foo.bar`, but when I try to open it as its ip address `1.2.3.4` I get a empty page with 404 status.
It seems tomcat looks for its welcome page and doesn't find it and return 404 page.

Now how may I fix this? I like to forward requests for host `1.2.3.4` to my `foo.bar`

Comment: This is probably virtual hosts function. See here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html#server.xml

Answer (score 0):

To deploy an application so that it's gets requests like `http://192.168.0.1:8080/` (i.e. with the context '/') you should either deploy an exploded WAR directory as `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT` or deploy a WAR file as `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT.war`. (Note, there are other options but this is the easiest way).

The `ROOT` and `ROOT.war` are special names which will instruct Tomcat to deploy it with a context path of '/'.  More on that [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming).

If it's not working and you get a 404, any number of things could be wrong.  Listing some common ones below.

1.) Your app is not deploying cleanly (i.e. it fails to start).  Check the logs to make sure it deploys cleanly.

2.) Your app is not setup correctly with a welcome-file.  Check your web.xml.

3.) Your app is not receiving the request.  If you have a reverse proxy in front of your server, check that it is properly sending the request to Tomcat.  You can use the access logs to confirm if Tomcat is getting the request.

4.) You have some bad Tomcat configuration.  Check `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`, `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`, `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/*.xml` and `META-INF/context.xml` for  tags which might be overriding the context path.

5.) You have a different `appBase`.  Tomcat looks for web apps to deploy in the `appBase` folder, which is an attribute on the  tag in server.xml.  It defaults to `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`.  Make sure this has not been changed, otherwise it won't deploy your app.

6.) Make sure that the  tag is configured to deploy the app.  See `autoDeploy` and `deployOnStartup`.  More on this [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html).